# Gunicorn + Django: ImportError: no module named

Tags: ubuntu, gunicorn

I am trying to set up an existing Django application using nginx and Gunicorn.  I am merely trying to test using `gunicorn` before I complete my nginx setup and testing.  I get the following error when I try to run the `gunicorn` command:

```
(venv)me@mymachine:/srv/test/proj$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 myapp.wsgi
[2015-09-18 09:40:30 -0400] [18838] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-09-18 09:40:30 -0400] [18838] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8001 (18838)
[2015-09-18 09:40:30 -0400] [18838] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-09-18 09:40:30 -0400] [18841] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18841
/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.forms.util module has been renamed. Use django.forms.utils instead.
  return f(*args, **kwds)

[2015-09-18 09:40:31 -0400] [18841] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/srv/test/proj/myapp/wsgi.py", line 30, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/srv/test/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/srv/test/proj/request/admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    from resource.models import ResourceRequest
ImportError: No module named 'resource.models'; 'resource' is not a package
```

Yet the file does exist and is set up as a package.  I can even do `runserver` and the dev server starts correctly with 0 errors.

Here is my wsgi.py:

```
"""
WSGI config for myapp project.

"""
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myapp.settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have searched high and low, none of the answers at stackoverflow or other sites have helped at all.  I have tried this in both python2 and python3 environments.

I have also tried:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 myapp.wsgi:application
```

and

```
gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings myapp.wsgi:application
```

Both with the same error.

What could the issue be?

EDIT:  I think this is the critical part of the error:

```
[2015-09-18 10:30:32 -0400] [19235] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
```

Is this a bug in Gunicorn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  The word `resource` is apparently a name conflict of some kind for Gunicorn.  Had to rename my app and all the references to `resources` to fix it.

Blah...